# Crash while update to 16.04. Can't boot now

Tags: boot, upgrade, 16.04, login

first of all: I am not into programming at all. I just use ubuntu, but have no idea how to fix the most simple problem…

I updated to 16.04. While updating the screen freezed and I had to shut down the computer. After restarting it shows a black screen:

Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS [laptop-name] tty1
[laptop-name] login:

After typing my login with password it alway gives:
login incorrect.

What can I do now?

Comment: Please try and get going on what I posted. Edit your question and I will remove my answer (or edit as we go along). Advice: if you do no want this investigated go for a re-install. Otherwise maybe it is best to get 20 rep and join us in chat here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room

Answer (score 0):

That means you ended in a "server" version (so with no working desktop).

The login in the normal login you see on a server. But it should let you log in with any of your accounts. If it does not more is wrong.

Boot into a live dvd and mount the disk that has your /home/ on it. Go to /home/$USER/ and do a `tail -n 100 .xsession-errors` and see if it holds errors.

Next check with `ls -la` in /home/$USER/ that the properties are ...

```
-rw-------  1 rinzwind rinzwind      57 aug  2 09:03 .Xauthority
-rw-------  1 rinzwind rinzwind     153 aug  2 09:03 .xsession-errors
```

(the name rinzwind should be your user name) for these 2 files.

**Edit your question with the result**. If you want we can see if we can get it back up by fixing any errors you found. I assume your password will be correct and it kicks you back to login due to problems with the login part.

**If you need it start making a backup of your files now.**

You could then forget about it all and re-install. That would get you back and restoring your backup will get you your files back too. All you will be missing is software you installed and settings you changed.

Comment: Work in progress. No upvotes please ;)

Comment: Wow! You put effort into your answers. Thumbs up.

Comment: Hey dude, thank you so much for your fast reply.

Comment: I now have a USB with the latest version of ubuntu on it. Could I simply reinstall the system without losing my data? At the moment I am unable to backup anything as I have no access to my data. I don't really get what you described above "Boot into a live dvd and mount the disk…" Passwort and Username are correct but the "non-server" version doesn't accept it. BTW: now it says "tty2" instead of "tty1"...

Comment: Yes but BEST is to make a backup. If you do not format your /home/ it will keep all your files and settings but a backup is a lot more safe.

Comment: Ok, but 1. How can I do a backup if I don't have graphically/visually access to my datas/folders? and 2. How can I reinstall without losing data? (This article https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation stops when it gets difficult.

Comment: Command line has enough features for you to do that ;) Insert a USB stick. That will get mounted in /media/ with a unique name. You can then use `cp` to copy files over to the USB. A method could be `cp /home/$USER/* /media/usbstick/` (what you need depends on your setup though) 2. Like I said: don't format the partition that holds /home/.

Comment: Ok, then I'll try to reinstall. I'll do as in the article above described: choose manual partitioning ("Something-else" option), then select Ubuntu system partition. But how should I sett its mount point then? Just "/"? I'll keep the same format type, the same size, and untick the "Format" checkbox. But should I use Ext4, Ext3 or something else?

Comment: I failed trying to reinstall. Now I wanted to do at least a backup to access my files which I need today. I tried to access command line/terminal with holding CTRL + Alt + T but I can only access BIOS.